# Bit.cloud not showing my components tests

Tags: bit.dev

Bit.cloud is not showing my tests, but they are right there, and they show when running `bit start` locally. Sadly, the link on the no tests page directing me to learn how to add tests goes to a 404.

I the workspace is public, have a look and see here, the first link the is "tests" tab showing empty, [https://bit.cloud/koodoo/koomeleon/second-charge/validation/~tests](https://bit.cloud/koodoo/koomeleon/second-charge/validation/%7Etests), and this link is a test for the the same component [https://bit.cloud/koodoo/koomeleon/second-charge/validation/~code/eligibility/dateOfBirth/index.test.ts](https://bit.cloud/koodoo/koomeleon/second-charge/validation/%7Ecode/eligibility/dateOfBirth/index.test.ts).

Also, side note, can I get an invite to the Slack workspace please? Again the link on the bit.cloud page goes to a sign-in page for the workspace `bit-dev-community`, but there is no way of registering or requesting an invite.

Please and thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

The reason your tests are not being show is due to its extension.
Tests are configured to use the `.spec.ts` extension to work.

**Solution**

Having said so, rename your test to:

```
vaidation.spec.tsx
```

and it will work.

edit: forgot to add the 'x' at the end of '.tsx'

Comment: Ah cool, thank you for your reply! So I need `.ts` files, not `.tsx`?

Comment: Won't make any difference as long as you don't have JSX on the file. Will work with both.